# Inno Setup: Getting Compiler Error "Semicolon (;) Expected" when creating a Boolean or Integer Procedure

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Hello I need to create a `Boolean Procedure` in my Inno Setup Script.

I added my procedure correctly but when try to compile script I am getting error:

> Line 2416 , Column 25 , Semicolon (;) Expected.

This is the code I added.

```
procedure WizardCloser(): Boolean;  <<<THIS IS THE LINE 2416>>>
begin
InitializeWizard;
end;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `procedure` does not have a return type.

You probably wanted to implement a `function`.

---

Other notes:

- Calling an event function (`InitializeWizard`) from a custom function seems like a bad idea. The event functions are called by Inno Setup. You should not call them, in general.
- You have to set the function return value, by setting the `Result`.